# How could I get Chrome Extensions off when I inspect web elements?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I had installed dozen of Chrome Extensions.
But when I "right click" > "inspect element" in Chrome to check my html structure,
I don't want to see anything from Extensions.

here is a simple page debugger view in Firefox & in Chrome.

clear and pretty in Firebug:
[image: clear and pretty in Firefox]

chaos in Chrome:
[image: chaos in Chrome]

I just need a clear view in Chrome debugger :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till date there is no way to isolate DOM view from [`Chrome Developer Tools`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) barring Chrome Extensions.

#### Work Around #1:

I suggest you to Open page in [`Incognito Mode`](http://www.google.co.in/goodtoknow/manage-data/incognito-mode/), where your extensions are (Most probably) inactive this eliminates extension code being visible in DOM.

#### Work Around #2:

Create another [`profile`](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059) for Chrome Browser, where you can find pure DOM View.

Comment: Work Around #3: Try using my Chrome Extension called "[Context](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context/aalnjolghjkkogicompabhhbbkljnlka)" that allows to group other extensions and easily enable/disable these groups.